# "File too small for architecture arm64", "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 "

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I just tried to run an application on my iPad and got this error:

```
ld: file too small (length=0) file '(PathToMyProjectBuild)/Objects-normal/arm64/Palette.o' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

My app runs great on iPhone and was gracefully running on my iPad, then suddenly I got this. What does it even mean and how can I solve the issue, since I am developing this app to mainly use it on my iPad, not iPhone (Though it is universal)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error happens after you interrupted a build.   Product/Clean will usually fix it.

I believe the compiler is trying to save binary data in a file/space that was partially allocated (and not cleaned up) by the interrupted build but the new binary data is larger than the previous one which is likely a zero-byte file.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes cleaning the project is not the best option because it takes long time to recompile everything from scratch. Most of the time there is only a single (in rare cases 2 or 3) file that produces the error.

To fix the issue simply remove that exact file from terminal and re-build by pasting the full path after `rm` command. In your case it would be:

```
$ rm (PathToMyProjectBuild)/Objects-normal/arm64/Palette.o
```

Comment: This is a good answer, althoug it is prone to human error. You should get more votes, here's mine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and this solution worked:
Copy the code from the palette.swift file somewhere.
Delete the palette.swift file from the navigator in xCode.
I tried to compile it, I get the error palette. does not exist.
Create a new palette.swift and paste the code into it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34739443)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).